# What's the way to say "too/also/as well" in Taiwanese?

Tags: word-requests

I would like to learn to say "I love you too" in the Hokkien dialect, as my boyfriend's from Taiwan, and I would like to surprise him. But I can't find the way to say it online, and I've heard him pronounce it something like, "Wo ai lu." I think the Mandarin way is to say, "Wo ai ni," and "Wo ye ai ni," but I'm not sure. Can anyone answer me? I would like the characters, but also the romanization. And for this, as I wasn't clear before, I actually mean for the Hokkien, as it's no surprise to him I know kind of how to say the Mandarin. I'd like the romanization so I can say it to him. But I would also like to be able to write it, since we may take classes together, and we've been known to write notes to each other.

Comment: Mandarin is 我愛你 (Wǒ ài nǐ) and 我也愛你 (Wǒ yě ài nǐ.)

Comment: I was looking for the Hokkien, I was aware vaguely of the Mandarin. Thank you, for the answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

There are three words corresponding to Mandarin "也" in Taiwanese Hokkien.

- 也 [iā](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/result_detail.jsp?n_no=184&curpage=1&sample=%E4%B9%9F&radiobutton=1&querytarget=2&limit=20&pagenum=1&rowcount=11)
- 亦 i̍k
- 嘛 [mā](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/result_detail.jsp?n_no=10417&curpage=1&sample=%E4%B9%9F&radiobutton=1&querytarget=2&limit=20&pagenum=1&rowcount=11)

I believe that in colloquial Hokkien, 也 is used exclusively in co-ordinated constructions, of the form "也 X 也 Y", which isn't what you want here. It is 嘛 that you're looking for.

Comment: Then would it be, 我嘛愛你 (góa mā ài lì)?

Comment: @XianLu yes you are right

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will study it well, and I hope to be able to say it right.

Comment: For Taiwanese Hokkien (闽南语), you might want to watch their drama. There's alot of famous drama up there.

Comment: @Raynoceros I didn't see this before, but I did watch a drama listed as Taiwanese, Fall in Love With Me (Ai Shang Liang Ge Wo, I believe is the original name), but it was in Mandarin, I'm pretty sure. They used 'wo ai ni' instead of 'goa ai li.' Was I missing something, or was that just not the one to watch for Hokkien dialect?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that the Taiwanese (Hokkien) dialect is very similar to mandarin, except that the intonation and pronunciation varies in a subtle way.

The writing should be exactly the same, unless you want to write it in a way that reflects the actually sounds (as they do sometimes).

我愛你 (góa ài lì)

Tip: I think góa is a little bit difficult to pronounce, so you might just try to say 'wa' instead.